# SupportedMediaTypes not used when doing content negotiation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, content-negotiation

I have created a new formatter in order to handle content negotiation.

```
public TiffImageFormatter()
{
    SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/tiff"));
}

public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
{
    return type == typeof(byte[]);
}

public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
{
    return type == typeof(byte[]);
}
```

But when running

```
var negotiator = Configuration.Services.GetContentNegotiator();
var type = negotiator.Negotiate(typeof(byte[]), Request, Configuration.Formatters);
```

The supported media types are not taken into consideration instead "CanWritetype" is the only condition determining what accept type to use.

Accept: image/*, image/png, image/tiff, */* should result in image/tiff but
Accept: image/png should return in null allowing me to send not acceptable.

How can I determine which is the correct media type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`MediaTypeFormatter.MediaTypeMappings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.mediatypeformatter.mediatypemappings(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter.MediaTypeMappings) and add the relevant `Accept` headers:

```
public TiffImageFormatter()
{
    SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/tiff"));
    MediaTypeMappings.Add(
                new RequestHeaderMapping("Accept", "image\tiff", 
                                          StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase,
                                          false, "image\tiff"));
}
```

This [*blog post*](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-web-api-mediatypeformatters-with-mediatypemappings) explains the algorithm for media type matching if you need any further information.